# Error using predict_generator with custom generator in Keras R interface

Tags: r, keras

I have been reading Deep Learning with R, and in chapter 6, generators are introduced. The following is the generator that yields (samples, outputs) which has no issue when used in fit_generator or evaluate_generator:

```
generator <- function(data, lookback, delay, min_index, max_index,
                      shuffle = FALSE, batch_size = 60, step = 1) {
  if (is.null(max_index))
    max_index <- nrow(data) - delay - 1
  i <- min_index + lookback
  function() {
    if (shuffle) {
      rows <- sample(c( (min_index+lookback) : max_index ), size = batch_size)
    } else {
      if (i + batch_size >= max_index)
        i <<- min_index + lookback
      rows <- c(i : min(i + batch_size - 1, max_index))
      rows
      length(rows)
      i <<- i + length(rows)
    }

    samples <- array(0, dim = c(length(rows), 
                                lookback / step,
                                dim(data)[[-1]]))
    targets <- array(0, dim = c(length(rows)))

    for (j in 1:length(rows)) {
      indices <- seq(rows[[j]] - lookback, rows[[j]], 
                     length.out = dim(samples)[[2]])
      samples[j,,] <- data[indices,]
      targets[[j]] <- data[rows[[j]] + delay, 9]
    }            

    list(samples, targets)
  }
}

test_gen <- generator(
  data,
  lookback = lookback,
  delay = delay,
  min_index = validation_index+1,
  max_index = NULL,
  step = step,
  batch_size = batch_size
)
## no issues here
test_steps <- (nrow(data) - validation_index+1 - lookback) / batch_size
perf <- my_model %>% evaluate_generator(test_gen, steps = test_steps)
```

however, when trying to change the generator to only yield samples:

```
generator_pred <- function(data, lookback, delay, min_index, max_index,
                      shuffle = FALSE, batch_size = 60, step = 1) {
  if (is.null(max_index))
    max_index <- nrow(data) - delay - 1
  i <- min_index + lookback
  function() {
    if (shuffle) {
      rows <- sample(c( (min_index+lookback) : max_index ), size = batch_size)
    } else {
      if (i + batch_size >= max_index)
        i <<- min_index + lookback
      rows <- c(i : min(i + batch_size - 1, max_index))
      rows
      length(rows)
      i <<- i + length(rows)
    }

    samples <- array(0, dim = c(length(rows), 
                                lookback / step,
                                dim(data)[[-1]]))

    for (j in 1:length(rows)) {
      indices <- seq(rows[[j]] - lookback, rows[[j]], 
                     length.out = dim(samples)[[2]])
      samples[j,,] <- data[indices,]
    }            
    samples
  }
}

test_gen_pred <- generator_pred(
      data,
      lookback = lookback,
      delay = delay,
      min_index = validation_index+1,
      max_index = NULL,
      step = step,
      batch_size = batch_size
    )

test_steps <- (nrow(data) - validation_index+1 - lookback) / batch_size
predict_generator(my_model, test_gen_pred, steps = test_steps)
```

I get an error about the equivalent python generator returning an array that is used in a comparison:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1064:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PBORDE~1\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\PBORDE~1\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PBORDE~1\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 579, in data_generator_task
    generator_output = next(self._generator)
  File "C:/Users/pbordeaux/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/reticulate/python\rpytools\generator.py", line 23, in __next__
    return self.next()
  File "C:/Users/pbordeaux/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/reticulate/python\rpytools\generator.py", line 39, in next
    if (res == self.completed):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I read that the generator must return the same object that predict_on_batch takes as input. I ran the following successfully:

```
test_gen_pred <- generator_pred(
  data,
  lookback = lookback,
  delay = delay,
  min_index = validation_index+1,
  max_index = NULL,
  step = step,
  batch_size = batch_size
)

t <- test_gen_pred()
predict_on_batch(my_model, t)
```

Is the generator interface not being implemented correctly? I checked that when test_gen_pred() is called that it returns a tensor with the correct shape, and it does, as I can call predict_on_batch successfully with a call from it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`series_generator()`](https://kerasgenerator.netlify.com/reference/series_generator) from [`kerasgenerator`](https://kerasgenerator.netlify.com) package, which provide `return_target` option if you want to use it for prediction.

**Some quick example**:

Make some supervised settings first:

```
# example data
data <- data.frame(
  x = runif(80),
  y = runif(80),
  z = runif(80)
)

# variables
x <- c("x", "y")
y <- 2:3

# supervise settings
lookback <- 10
timesteps <- 10

# number of train sample
train_length <- 40

# data settings
batch_size <- 10

# train row indices
train_end <- nrow(data)
train_start <- train_end - train_length + 1

# number of steps to see full data
train_steps <- train_length / batch_size
```

Then you could define the generators like this:

```
# import libs
library(kerasgenerator)

# train generator
train_gen <- series_generator(
  data = data,
  y = y,
  x = x,
  lookback = lookback,
  timesteps = timesteps,
  start_index = train_start,
  end_index = train_end,
  batch_size = batch_size,
  return_target = TRUE
)

# predict generator
predict_gen <- series_generator(
  data = data,
  y = y,
  x = x,
  lookback = lookback,
  timesteps = timesteps,
  start_index = train_start,
  end_index = train_end,
  batch_size = batch_size,
  return_target = FALSE
)
```

Let's try the data generators on an example model:

```
# import libs
library(keras)

# initiate a sequential model
model <- keras_model_sequential()

# define the model
model %>%

  # layer lstm
  layer_lstm(
    name = "lstm",
    input_shape = list(timesteps, length(x)),
    units = 16,
    dropout = 0.1,
    recurrent_dropout = 0.1,
    return_sequences = FALSE
  ) %>%

  # layer output
  layer_dense(
    name = "output",
    units = length(y)
  )

# compile the model
model %>% compile(
  optimizer = "rmsprop",
  loss = "mse"
)

# model summary
summary(model)

# set number of epochs
epochs <- 10

# model fitting
history <- model %>% fit_generator(
  generator = train_gen,
  steps_per_epoch = train_steps,
  epochs = epochs
)

# history plot
plot(history)

# evaluate on train dataset
model %>% evaluate_generator(
  generator = train_gen,
  steps = train_steps
)

# predict on train dataset
model %>% predict_generator(
  generator = predict_gen,
  steps = train_steps
)
```

If you interested in forecasting, it also provide [`forecast_generator()`](https://kerasgenerator.netlify.com/reference/forecast_generator). See the [vignettes](https://kerasgenerator.netlify.com/articles/timeseries) for full example.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the package.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking for the exact same answer for a few days now, finally got it to work by making my pred_generator returning a **list** (instead of samples directly)!

In your case:

```
generator_pred <- function(data, lookback, delay, min_index, max_index,
                  shuffle = FALSE, batch_size = 60, step = 1) {
    <...>            
    list(samples)
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! i had ended up using a different setup altogether bc i could not get it working. much appreciated

Comment: @pbordeaux could you please share how did you solve it?